# Add a random number or date code to a import url?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need some help adding a number to an import URL to prevent caching in Google app scripts, here is my current script:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1').setValue('=importdata("https://examplesite.com/stuff.csv")')
}
```

I want to add a random number at the end of the URL, something like:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1').setValue('=importdata("https://examplesite.com/stuff.csv?75395")')
}
```

I have tried creating a var with a random number generator but it just doesn't seem to want to play ball!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
function myFunction() {
  const rand = 1000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) // Make Random Number from 1000 to 11000
  const url = `=importdata("https://examplesite.com/stuff.csv?${rand}")` // Put it into the url
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1').setValue(url)
}
```

OR as suggested by @Reyno:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const rand = Date.now() // Make Random Number by sampling current date in ms, will always be different
  const url = `=importdata("https://examplesite.com/stuff.csv?${rand}")` // Put it into the url
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1').setValue(url)
}
```

Comment: Or just use `Date.now()` instead of picking a random number between `x` and `y`

Comment: True, will add that in

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getTime()` of Date as follows:

```
function myFunction() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1').setValue(`=importdata("https://examplesite.com/stuff.csv?${new Date().getTime()}")`)
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [Date.prototype.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime#:%7E:text=The%20getTime()%20method%20returns,uses%20UTC%20for%20time%20representation.)